# WPF Caliburn.Micro and TabControl with UserControls issue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol, caliburn.micro

I'm pretty sure this has been answered somewhere, but I can't seem to find it for the life of me.

I'm trying to use a TabControl to switch between UserControls (each tab is different, so not using Items)

Here's the breakdown:
I have my mainview, and 3 usercontrols.  Mainview has a tab control - each tab should display a different user control.

I could easily just set the tabcontrol contect to the usercontrol using 

But then it isn't bound to the viewmodel, only the view.

So I'm using Conductor in my VM, and ActivateItem.  Here's where it starts to get weird / frustrating.  Application starts with Tab0 selected, but Tab2 (last tab) content.  Click on any other tab, loads the correct ViewModel for that tab.  Click back to Tab0, loads the correct content there as well.

How do I get this to stop?  Also, I'd really like it if switching tabs doesn't re-initialize the viewmodel again, clearing out fields that have already been entered.

Anyways, here's some of my source, I'm going to just drop this here and work on something else before I break my mouse.

View:

```
<TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row ="1">
        <TabItem Header="PC Information">
            <Grid>
                <ContentControl x:Name="LoadRemoteInfo" cal:View.Model="{Binding ActiveItem}"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Remote Tools">
            <Grid>
                <ContentControl x:Name="LoadRemoteTools" cal:View.Model="{Binding ActiveItem}"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="CHRemote">
            <Grid>
                <ContentControl x:Name="LoadCHRemote" cal:View.Model="{Binding ActiveItem}"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>

    </TabControl>
```

and the ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel : Conductor<object>
{
    RemoteInfoViewModel remoteInfo = new RemoteInfoViewModel();
    RemoteToolsViewModel remoteTools = new RemoteToolsViewModel();
    CHRemoteViewModel chRemote = new CHRemoteViewModel();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ActivateItem(remoteInfo);
    }

    public void LoadRemoteInfo()
    {
        ActivateItem(remoteInfo);
    }

    public void LoadRemoteTools()
    {
        ActivateItem(remoteTools);
    }

    public void LoadCHRemote()
    {
        ActivateItem(chRemote);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

May I suggest a tad different route?

It's something that I have been successfully doing in master-details scenarios. Let's say you have a collection of child view models. I'll prepare a marker interface for all those items, of course you can add properties/methods you see fit if there are such methods that span all child view models:

```
public interface IMainScreenTabItem : IScreen
{
}
```

You can be quite sure that you want all your child models to be `Screen`s (or, in case of nested scenarios, `Conductor`s). It makes them have the full initialization/activation/deactivation cycle available.

Then, the child view models:

```
public sealed class ChRemoteViewModel : Screen, IMainScreenTabItem
{
    public ChRemoteViewModel()
    {
        DisplayName = "CH Remote";
    }
}

public sealed class PcInfoViewModel : Screen, IMainScreenTabItem
{
    public PcInfoViewModel()
    {
        DisplayName = "PC Info";
    }
}

public sealed class RemoteToolsViewModel : Screen, IMainScreenTabItem
{
    public RemoteToolsViewModel()
    {
        DisplayName = "Remote Tools";
    }
}
```

`DisplayName` will be displayed as a header text. It's a good practice to make those classes sealed, because `DisplayName` is a virtual property, and it's a big no-no to call virtual methods in a constructor of a class that's not sealed.

Then, you can add corresponding views and set your IoC container of choice registrations - you have to register your all child view models as classes implementing the `IMainScreenTabItem` and then:

```
public class MainViewModel : Conductor<IMainScreenTabItem>.Collection.OneActive
{
    public MainViewModel(IEnumerable<IMainScreenTabItem> tabs)
    {
        Items.AddRange(tabs);
    }
}
```

Where the `MainView.xaml` is just:

```
<TabControl Name="Items"/>
```

And it just works. It's also *very* nice and convenient solution if your child view models take multiple dependencies (e.g. database access, logger, validation mechanism etc), now you can have the IoC do all the heavy lifting instead of instantiating them by hand.

One thing here though: the tabs will be placed in the same order the classes are injected. If you want to have a control over the ordering, you can order them in `MainViewModel` constructor by either passing a custom `IComparer<IMainScreenTabItem>` or adding some property you can `OrderBy` or select to the `IMainScreenTabItem` interface. The default selected item will be the first one in the `Items` list.

Other option is to make the `MainViewModel` take three parameters:

```
public MainViewModel(ChRemoteViewModel chRemoteViewModel, PcInfoViewModel pcInfo, RemoteToolsViewModel remoteTools)
{
    // Add the view models above to the `Items` collection in any order you see fit
}
```

Although when you have more than 2 - 3 child view models (and you can easily get more), it's going to get messy quick.

About the 'clearing' part. The view models created by IoC confrom to the regular life-cycle: they're initialized at most once (`OnInitialize`), then deactivated each time they are navigated away from `OnDeactivate(bool)` and activated when they're navigated to (`OnActivate`). The `bool` parameter in `OnDeactivate` indicates whether the view model is just deactivated or completely 'closed' (e.g. when you close the dialog window and navigate away). If you completely close the view model, it will be re-initialized next time it's shown.

That means that any bound data will be retained between `OnActivate` calls and you'd have to explicitly clear it in `OnDeactivate`. What's more, if you keep the strong reference to your child view models, then even after you call `OnDeactivate(true)`, the data will still be there on next initialization - that's because IoC injected view models are created *once* (unless you inject the factory function in a form of `Func<YourViewModel>`), and then initialized/activated/deactivated on demand.

---

#### EDIT

About the bootstrapper, I'm not quite sure what kind of IoC container you're using. My sample uses [SimpleInjector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/), but you can do the same just as easily with e.g. Autofac:

```
public class AppBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<MainViewModel>
{
    private Container container;

    /// <summary>
    /// Override to configure the framework and setup your IoC container.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        container = new Container();
        container.Register<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
        container.Register<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
        var viewModels =
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                .DefinedTypes.Where(x => x.GetInterface(typeof(IMainScreenTabItem).Name) != null && !x.IsAbstract && x.IsClass);
        container.RegisterAll(typeof(IMainScreenTabItem), viewModels);
        container.Verify();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Override this to provide an IoC specific implementation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="service">The service to locate.</param><param name="key">The key to locate.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The located service.
    /// </returns>
    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        if (service == null)
        {
            var typeName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().DefinedTypes.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(key)).Select(x => x.AssemblyQualifiedName).Single();

            service = Type.GetType(typeName);
        }
        return container.GetInstance(service);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return container.GetAllInstances(service);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        container.InjectProperties(instance);
    }
}
```

Note the `viewModels` registration in `Configure`.

Comment: Very nice writeup, seriously.  I'm going to implement this now and I'll let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Well, I'm still learning caliburn / mvvm, so I'm at a loss here - I need to do something in my bootstrapper, just not sure what.  Can you possibly point me in the right direction?  I tried following https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customizing%20The%20Bootstrapper but no luck.  This is making me feel like a complete noob lol.

Comment: @JustinMangum Added an edit with a sample addressing your concerns. If you're using e.g. MEF, I won't really be able to help you that much, because it concerns very IoC-specific methods and I have no experience with MEF :)

Comment: That SimpleInjector worked.  I'll have to read up on that - I haven't used MEF before either, and couldn't seem to get it to like me.  Seriously, thank you for the help.  Before, the app was functional, just not to my liking, and I wanted to learn how to do this properly.  Like I said, still new to MVVM (been meaning to learn it for a long time), so this really helped me out, as the bootstrapper is a big step.

Comment: The SimpleInjector code sample no longer works as of v3.0.  Here's how to fix it: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/migrating-to-simple-injector-30-with-caliburn-micro-bootstrap-changes

Comment: You can also implement DisplayName like this: `public override string DisplayName
        {
            get { return "Database Settings"; }
            set { }
        }` to avoid calling the virtual member in a constructor.

Comment: This is a good approach.
However after I implemented it in my app I realized that there is no way to set hot key to the tab items. I've ~20 tabs and need to quickly navigate btw them using hot keys.

Comment: I missed something here. I tried this solution, but in the MainViewModel constructor the Items.Add(tabs) does not add any tabs. The second solution, explicitly naming the tabs as constructor parameters, results into an error message saying I need a parameterless constructor. This clearly does not work. I can create the tabs in the ShellViewModel as class parameters, I get it working, but it probably is not a good design. I use the Caliburn.Micro SimpleContainer, which seems to work fine overall. Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Patryk Ćwiek's great answer!

If you are already using Caliburn Mirco and don't want to add more dependencies, you can use their `SimpleContainer` in place of SimpleInjector or AutoFac.

Just register the implementations like so:

```
container.AllTypesOf<IMainScreenTabItem>(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```