# WPF Caliburn.Micro and TabControl - changing tab, not changing model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol, caliburn.micro

I'm kind of newbie in WPF&MVVM&Caliburn so I beg your indulgence :)

I have a problem with binding TabControl with dynamically created models. Tabcontrol is being created correctly but changing tab is not switching viewmodel used to bind "view" (I'm using viewmodel first approach)

I've made my solution basing on this question: [WPF Caliburn.Micro and TabControl with UserControls issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883868/wpf-caliburn-micro-and-tabcontrol-with-usercontrols-issue/20885027)

This is my model definition:

```
public interface IMainScreenTabItem : IScreen
{
}

public class MainViewTestTabsViewModel : Conductor<IMainScreenTabItem>.Collection.OneActive
{
    public MainViewTestTabsViewModel(IEnumerable<IMainScreenTabItem> tabs)
    {
        Items.Add(new ViewTabModel("Foo1"));
        Items.Add(new ViewTabModel("Foo2"));
        Items.AddRange(tabs);
    }
}

public sealed class ViewTabModel : Screen, IMainScreenTabItem
{
    public ViewTabModel(string displayName)
    {
        DisplayName = displayName;
    }
}
```

And here is the view MainViewTestTabsView:

```
<UserControl  x:Class="TestWpfApp.Views.MainViewTestTabsView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApp.Views"
    xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:TestWpfApp.ViewModels"
    xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Width="500" Height="500">
<Grid>
    <TabControl Name="Items">
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Label  cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}" x:Name="DisplayName" Height="200" Width="200" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

What I want to achieve - is to have TabControl with many tabs. Each tab has the same "view" (declared in DataTemplate) but to bind this view I want to use different viewModels (to be specific - the same model class [ViewTabModel ] but with different data)

The size of tabs is to be declared at runtime as well as the data, which should be in the ViewTabModel model.

In example below - I have two tabs, but changing them is not changing the Label (i have all the Time: "Foo1" Label, even if I click "Foo2" tab)

I use caliburn.micro as a framework - with autofac bootstrap (if it matters)
And I use propertyChanged.Fody (https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) to omit all the propertychanged stuff in viewmodels.

What am I doing wrong?

=== UPDATE ===

Attaching minimal reproduction solution:

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0b909bfd31a588dda99655f366eddad420170801192103/1d094a

Plese, help! :)

=== UPDATE 2 ===

Is anything unclear about my question ?:) Still no comments, no anwsers event with bounty on it.

=== UPDATE 3 ===

I've already posted COMPLETE view page (xaml) and COMPLETE model code (this is only this)

I'm posting also AppBoostraper.cs and AppWindowManager.cs (but i suppose it is irrelevat here)

AppBoostrapper.cs

```
using Autofac;
using TestWpfApp.ViewModels;

namespace TestWpfApp {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Caliburn.Micro;

    public class AppBootstrapper : CaliburnMetroAutofacBootstrapper<MainViewTestTabsViewModel>
    {
        protected override void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<AppWindowManager>().As<IWindowManager>().SingleInstance();
            var assembly = typeof(ShellViewModel).Assembly;
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
                .Where(item => item.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel") && item.IsAbstract == false)
                .AsSelf()
                .SingleInstance();
        }
    }
}
```

It is inheriting CaliburnMetroAutofacContainer (https://github.com/ziyasal/Caliburn.Metro)

AppWindowsManager.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Caliburn.Metro.Core;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;

namespace TestWpfApp
{
    public class AppWindowManager : MetroWindowManager
    {
        public override MetroWindow CreateCustomWindow(object view, bool windowIsView)
        {
            if (windowIsView)
            {
                return view as ShellView;
            }

            return new ShellView
            {
                Content = view
            };
        }
    }
}
```

=== UPDATE 4 ===
Apprently, changing control from:

> cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}" x:Name="DisplayName"

to:

> Content="{Binding DisplayName}"

Did the work. Although i'm not quite sure why?

Now i want to do exactly the same. Only this time i want my view to be binded. So ViewModel is exactly the same. But this time:

MainViewTestTabsView

```
<UserControl  x:Class="TestWpfApp.Views.MainViewTestTabsView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApp.Views"
    xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:TestWpfApp.ViewModels"
    xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Width="500" Height="500">
<Grid>
    <TabControl Name="Items">
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <local:ViewTab cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

and ViewTab view is :

```
<UserControl  x:Class="TestWpfApp.Views.ViewTab"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApp.Views"
    xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:TestWpfApp.ViewModels"
    xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Width="300" Height="300">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Label x:Name="DisplayName"></Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

=== Update 5 => Happy final ===
I've been sugested I should stick to the ViewModel first convention (as i declared i'm using) and my attempts was somhow view first. So i've changed it to:

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding ActiveItem}" />
```

But nothing is rendered then

If i declare it like this :

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />
```

There is only message saying : "Cannot find view for : [my_namspece].ViewTabModel
It was weird and get me thinking. Maybe i'm not sticking to the convention. And it was true...

My model was called:

> ViewTabModel

Whereas it should be :

> ViewTabViewModel

exactly the same thing with view. It should be called:

> ViewTabView.xaml

After that, such construction:

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />
```

Is working correctly!! Thank you arcticwhite and grek40 for leading me to this solution

Comment: Are you missing binding?

Comment: I used Caliburn long back. Have you tried ActivateItem(viewmodel  here)?

Comment: On change of tab you need to activate the view using ActivateItem

Comment: Maybe you can propose, where and how to put this "ActivateItem" - it is not obvious as it sounds :)

I would be grateful :)

Comment: https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens,%20Conductors%20and%20Composition. Here they have example

Comment: Each of examples there is basing on activating "new" model. And once i create TabControl - i have model created for each page. I've copy pasted example to my MainViewTestTabModel :

        public override void ActivateItem(IMainScreenTabItem item)
        {
            base.ActivateItem(item);

            if (item != null)
                item.Activate();
            
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => item);
        }

Still no difference

Comment: There isn't one person, who knows the answer?:)

Comment: What .NET version are you using?

Comment: You know - there is this project attached (ready for download and check) :) Attached as wetransfer file. Nevertheless, my framework is 4.6.2

Comment: The problem with the files is that it reports that all t he references doesn't exists.

Comment: Regarding your Update 2: downloading some web project, fixing up dependencies, finding your problem? Doesn't sound all that appealing to me and definitely is nothing I can quickly do in a break at work - can't even access the wetransfer with company proxy. A minimal example should be minimal enough to fit into your question completely. However, I'm not a caliburn.micro expert, so maybe others can answer more easily.

Comment: @arcticwhite - try "Update-Package –reinstall" in nuget console. If it doesn't help - the only resolution i can think of is to remove porpertyChanged.fody and install it once again (this is probably causing problems)

Comment: @grek40 - the code i've pasted is "minimal enough" to fit into my question. Nevertheless i've decided to give ready solution for people to be able to download and see it "live" and maybe try to change something (and get it working)

Comment: You state you use *"viewmodel first approach"*. Please review the following: https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions Look for the headline **View First** to the bullet-list at the end. Read carefully about `Bind.Model`, `Bind.ModelWithoutContext` and `View.Model`. As far as I understand, `Bind.Model` is not matching your usage (and is certainly not viewmodel first approach).

Comment: Thank's @grek40 for this info. I've read it but still quite unsure how to change it. I will update main question with my attempts

Comment: is it answered?

Comment: Yes - see  === update 5 === ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I had some time to test your sample project... as I commented, you should chose the right binding type...

From [All About Actions](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions), I guess there will be other documentation sources around, listing the same basic information:

> - **Bind.Model** – View-First - Set’s the Action.Target and DataContext properties to the specified instance. Applies conventions
>     to the view. String values are used to resolve an instance from the
>     IoC container. (Use on root nodes like Window/UserControl/Page.)
> - **Bind.ModelWithoutContext** - View-First - Set’s the Action.Target to the specified instance. Applies conventions to the view. (Use
>     inside of DataTemplate.)
> - **View.Model** – ViewModel-First – Locates the view for the specified VM instance and injects it at the content site. Sets the VM
>     to the Action.Target and the DataContext. Applies conventions to the
>     view.

As said, I'm not a caliburn expert, so I had to try it... the second option looked best to me (*"Use inside of DataTemplate"*), so here is the working result:

From

```
<Label  cal:Bind.Model="{Binding}" x:Name="DisplayName" Height="200" Width="200" />
```

replace to

```
<Label cal:Bind.ModelWithoutContext="{Binding}" x:Name="DisplayName" Height="200" Width="200" />
```

and its working.

Actually, I'd advise to introduce the model in the surrounding stackpanel instead (the datatemplate root)

```
<StackPanel cal:Bind.ModelWithoutContext="{Binding}">
    <Label x:Name="DisplayName" Height="200" Width="200" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I've managed to run it another way :) By using : <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" /> It was not working at the beginning (and i tried this way - even before i've posted question on SOF. But it was not working (for a reason) more of this in the main question.

How can I split bounty between two people? Because you and arctiwhite help me a lot.

Comment: You can't split the bounty. However, you can accept the answer that you consider to be the best fit for your question and bounty the other one in honor of paying attention to your problem ;)

Comment: Yeah, I've already found a discussion on this topic on Stack meta. I disagree with the result of their conclusion. arcticwhite helped me with initial phase of the question. You've helped me by directing me into final conclusion. None of those two answers were full, complex and final. Yey it would be shame to loose 50 reputation points. Sorry guys - i must roll the dice:) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Okay...
I have already worked with `Caliburn.Micro`, so I can say I have some experience, not a pro, but I manage to make it working.

Your MainViewTestTabsViewModel.cs:

```
 public interface IMainScreenTabItem : IScreen
    {
    }

    public class MainViewTestTabsViewModel : Conductor<IMainScreenTabItem>.Collection.OneActive
    {
        public MainViewTestTabsViewModel(IEnumerable<IMainScreenTabItem> tabs)
        {

            Items.Add(new ViewTabModel() {DisplayName = "Test"});
            Items.Add(new ViewTabModel() { DisplayName = "Test2" });
            Items.Add(new ViewTabModel() { DisplayName = "Test3" });
            Items.AddRange(tabs);
        }
    }

    public class ViewTabModel : Screen, IMainScreenTabItem
    {
        public ViewTabModel()
        {

        }
    }
```

And your MainViewTestTabsView.xaml

```
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfApp.ViewModels"
    xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
   xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:TestWpfApp.Views"
    xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Width="500" Height="500">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl x:Name="Items" >
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label cal:Bind.ModelWithoutContext="{Binding}" x:Name="DisplayName" Height="200" Width="200"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

P.S. Why I removed your displayName variable in constructor... Because you don't need it, it's already in the `Caliburn:Micro.Screen` as a property.

**Edit #2**
The convention will work, just add `cal:Bind.ModelWithoutContext="{Binding}"` inside your `Label` (Edited the answer).

Comment: Yeah, it worked - nevertheless i don't know why. Shouldn't caliburn.micro bind data just by convention (x:Name was DisplayName after all)? It does fix minimal reproduction example - but it is still not helping with my real problem, which is a little bit more complicated. I will update my question. (what i need is to bind my custom viewModel with view)

Comment: So you're saying the right way to approach this problem is to use explicit bindings (`Content="{Binding DisplayName}"`) instead of relying on Conventions of caliburn.micro? I understand it is possible, but I think it defeats the original idea, specially since the `DisplayName` is supposedly only a minimal example for a fairly complex real-project structure. €dit: Piotr commented faster than me :)

Comment: The only thing, that amazes me - is that... not relying on convention = working correctly. I cannot comprehend it ;)

Just one more step and I'm ready to go. I only need t change this simple template to use declared view (and how to bind it) Update 4 will be in a minute

Comment: Update 4 is ready and waiting for ideas. I've tried Content="{Binding}" but without success