# WPF + Caliburn Micro + MVVM: TabItem handling

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabitem

I am trying to make a popup window which contains tabcontrol using WPF, Caliburn Micro and MVVM pattern, no need to use code behind in this case. The tabcontrol contains more than 1 tabitem. After digging some threads in SO for a while I combine the found solutions and can create the popup window and fill it with *tabcontrol and its tabitems* (*[I take it from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883868/wpf-caliburn-micro-and-tabcontrol-with-usercontrols-issue)*).

**Problem:** the tabitems show content (text) from view model but show no content from view. Please take a look the code attached here.

**Expected** I expect to see the text "Tab Item 1" as TabItem1 header and the text "Selection One" as content in TabItem1. Right now both the header and the content of TabItems contains same text "Tab Item 1".

Am I missing something? I attach here the code. Please feel free change the code. Any hints are highly appreciated.

Sequence of code:

- TabItem1, TabItem2 view and viewmodel
- ITabItem
- PopUp window view and viewmodel
- AppBootstrapper, Shell view and viewmodel

**TabItem1ViewModel** (TabItem2ViewModel has same content)

```
public class TabItem1ViewModel : Screen, ITabItem
{
    public TabItem1ViewModel() => DisplayName = "Tab Item 1";
}
```

**Attention:** in following TabItem view I use Label to show the text "Selection One", but this text doesn't appear at all. Only the display name "Tab Item 1" defined in view model appears as content of TabItem1

**TabItem1View** (TabItem2View has same content)

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="CmTabControl.Views.TabItem1View"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <TabItem x:Name="TabItem1" Header="{Binding Path=DisplayName}">
            <Grid x:Name="TabItem1ContentGrid">
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left"                     
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Content="Selection One" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**ITabItem** (yes, it is only empty interface)

```
public interface ITabItem : IScreen
{
}
```

**PopUpViewModel**

```
public class PopUpViewModel : Screen
{
    public PopUpViewModel()
    {
        TabItems.Add(new TabItem1ViewModel());
        TabItems.Add(new TabItem2ViewModel());
    }

    private readonly BindableCollection<ITabItem> _tabItems = new BindableCollection<ITabItem>();
    public BindableCollection<ITabItem> TabItems
    {
        get => _tabItems;
        set
        {
            if (_tabItems == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            _tabItems.Clear();
            _tabItems.AddRange(value);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TabItems);
        }
    }
}
```

**PopUpView**

```
<Window
    x:Class="CmTabControl.Views.PopUpView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CmTabControl.Views"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="PopUpView"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Margin="3,8,3,3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TabControl x:Name="TabItems" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**AppBootstrapper**

```
public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private readonly SimpleContainer _container = new SimpleContainer();

    public AppBootstrapper() => Initialize();
    protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key) => _container.GetInstance(serviceType, key);
    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType) => _container.GetAllInstances(serviceType);
    protected override void BuildUp(object instance) => _container.BuildUp(instance);

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        base.Configure();

        _container.Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>();
        _container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
        _container.Singleton<ShellViewModel>();
        _container.PerRequest<PopUpViewModel>(); // Or Singleton if there'll only ever be one
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(sender, e);
        DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>();
    }
}
```

**ShellViewModel**

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>.Collection.AllActive
{
    private IWindowManager _windowManager;

    public ShellViewModel(PopUpViewModel popUpVm)
    {
        DisplayName = "Shell Window";
        PopUpViewModel = popUpVm;
    }

    public PopUpViewModel PopUpViewModel { get; set; }

    public sealed override void ActivateItem(object item) => base.ActivateItem(item);

    public void OpenPopUp()
    {
        ActivateItem(PopUpViewModel);
        if (_windowManager == null) _windowManager = new WindowManager();
        _windowManager.ShowDialog(PopUpViewModel, null, null);
    }

    public sealed override string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

**ShellView**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="CmTabControl.Views.ShellView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="300"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Width="300" Height="300"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="OpenPopUp" Width="100" Height="35"
            Content="Open Popup" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Added:** Screenshot of Live Visual Tree.
[image]

Comment: If you run the `Snoop` or `Live Visual tree` debugging tool in Visual Studio then do you see `Grid/Label` as child of `TabItem`?

Comment: No, I see only TextBlock as Child of TabItem, no Label. I added the screenshot on my question above.

Comment: What do you expect to see and where is your PopupViewModel?

Comment: oh sorry. I just added the PopUpViewModel and its view. I expect to see "Tab Item 1" as TabItem1 header and the text "Selection One" as content in TabItem1. Right now both the header and the content of TabItems contains same text "Tab Item 1".

Comment: Is it important for you to bind a list to the TabControl?

Comment: Yes, it is important. So I can add the tab item and bind it in PopUpView easily. But please also explain about your idea without binding a list to the TabControl. Thx in advance.

Comment: If you have a fixed number of tabs you can define the tabs in your view and bind the individual viewModels.
Do you want a code example?

Comment: For the fixed number of tabs I dont need code example. I need the variable number of tabitems. The main issue is the content of TabItem doesn´t show the Label I defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that uses Templates:

**`PopUpViewModel`** add `SelectedTab`:

```
public sealed class PopUpViewModel : Screen
{
    private readonly BindableCollection<ITabItem> _tabItems = new BindableCollection<ITabItem>();
    private IScreen _selectedTab;


    public PopUpViewModel()
    {
        DisplayName = "Popup";
        TabItems.Add(new TabItem1ViewModel());
        TabItems.Add(new TabItem2ViewModel());
        SelectedTab = TabItems.FirstOrDefault();
    }


    public BindableCollection<ITabItem> TabItems
    {
        get => _tabItems;
        set
        {
            if(_tabItems == null)
                return;
            _tabItems.Clear();
            _tabItems.AddRange(value);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TabItems);
        }
    }

    public IScreen SelectedTab
    {
        get => _selectedTab;
        set
        {
            _selectedTab = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }
}
```

**`PopUpView`**:

```
<Grid Margin="3, 8, 3, 3"
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab,
                               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding DisplayName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Now you only add the TabItem content to your pages, **`TabItem1View`**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfTestApp.Views.Tabs.TabItem1View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTestApp.Views.Tabs"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="450"
             d:DesignWidth="800">

    <Grid x:Name="TabItem1ContentGrid">
        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Content="Selection One" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Edit:**

SelectedTab is just there so the first tab is selected by default.

Comment: Great answer. You get the bounty! :)

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help.